# Understanding the fulfillment of a condition required for applying the pasting lemma.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, proof-explanation, homotopy-theory

Here is the solution of the question (which asks us to prove that the relation of homotopy among maps $X \rightarrow Y$ is an equivalence relation):

> [image]

My question is about the last part of proving transitivity. Why while applying the Pasting lemma the author of the solution was sure that $X \times [0,1/2]$ and $X \times [1/2, 1]$ are closed even though we do not have any information about the closure of $X.$ Could anyone explain this point for me please?

Comment: Both subset is closed with respect to $X \times [0,1]$. The set $X$ is closed in itself and closed interval is closed in $[0,1]$. So product of $X$ with closed intervals is closed.

Comment: @Eumenes are you saying that we are using the fact that "any set is closed in itself" for the closure of $X$ .... as we do not require $X$ to be closed in general we just want it to be closed in itself .... am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total space we're working in, is $X \times I$ and $X \times [0,\frac12]$ is closed in it, because it's $\pi_2^{-1}[[0,\frac12]]$, the inverse image of the projection under a closed set. And by definition of the product topology these are closed in $X \times I$.

$X$ is closed in itself (as in any topology), but that's irrelevant.

Wherever $X$ "came from" (a subspace of some earlier space maybe), we're treating it as a space in its own right and put the product topology on $X \times I$.

Comment: Sorry I took the categorical definition of the product topology but I do not see why( by what you said at the end of your first paragraph) this leads to "these are closed in $X\times I$". could you please explain more?

Comment: @Smart20 I only use that the projections are continuous in the product topology and $[0,\frac12]$ and $[\frac12,1]$ are closed in $[0,1]$. Inverse images of closed sets under continuous maps are closed, that's all.